# If something is displayed on a page then go into if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I am newbie using **backbone**.

This is the code that I have so far.

```
if () {
    var object = {};
    _.extend(object, Backbone.Events);
    object.on('click_me', function() {
        console.log("test");
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#button', function(event) {
        object.trigger('click_me');
    });
}
```

It is clear that I didn't put anything inside the if statement. 
And I want to put in here for example if and input value is "something" from input field somewhere else on the page then go inside here, if it isn't then don't go inside. 
Let's say I got something like this.

```
<textarea id="template_code" type="text" class="AknTextareaField"></textarea>
```

So when I have `template_code` then I want to go in, if I don't have anything then I don't want to go in here.

Comment: `var elm = document.querySelector("#template_code"); if(elm == null)` or... `if (elm != null)` ... I haven't tried this, but at a guess it's as simple as that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You're asking about your code, but looking at it, it looks like you're going in the wrong direction. If you'd asked about what you are trying to do, we could show you how to do it the _backbone way_.

Comment: Hey Emile, thanks for replying to my question. So I would like to access id="something" and to change it when the user clicks on a button. As you can see I am really close to achieving just that using jQuery and as long as you can see the answers are written in jQuery. So just to have options I would like to have a solution in backbone also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i have understood correctly, you want the function to execute if you have an element with an id "template_code"? If so use the following

```
if (document.getElementById('template_code') !=null) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can check for the elements display property and do whatever you want inside the block

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('template_code')).display !== "none"
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to trigger an event on your input and you cant check the value of an input when the document load , since most of the time the value is empty for example

```
x = document.getElementById('template_code');

x.addEventListener('change',function(){
  if(x.value.length > 0) {
  // do your code here
}

})
```